# Application Insights Profiler for Cloud Services ApplicationInsightsProfiler sink key

Tags: azure-cloud-services, azure-application-insights-profiler

According to the documentation [Profile live Azure Cloud Services with Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/profiler-cloudservice).  The application insights key must be provided in the WadCfg.

```
<WadCfg>
  <DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration>...</DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration>
  <SinksConfig>
    <Sink name="MyApplicationInsightsProfiler">
      <!-- Replace with your own Application Insights instrumentation key. -->
      <ApplicationInsightsProfiler>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</ApplicationInsightsProfiler>
    </Sink>
  </SinksConfig>
</WadCfg>
```

However, when using ServiceConfiguration.*.cscfg files per environment, the application insights key is stored in the cscfg files, but the `<ApplicationInsightsProfile>` doesn't appear to honor the location.

How do you link the application insights key to the profiler sink in the WadCfg file. Or is there some other way to configure Application Insights Profiler per environment?

Answer (score 0):

Ended up creating a wadcfg transfrom in the build pipeline since there don't appear to be any built in mechanisms to handle this.